# Why value dismiss from input field in React, when useState is not used for value but for object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have here a textfield:

```js
<TextFieldItem
  primary="Barion ID"
  required="**"
  value={selectedOrganization?.barionId ?? ""}
  onChange={(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    selectedOrganization.barionId = event.target.value;
    setSelectedOrganization(selectedOrganization);
  }}
  onBlur={() => validateBarionId()}
  disabled={
    !selectedOrganizationId || !userFbId || editBarionIdIsDisabled
  }
  placeholder="e-mail"
  helperText={barionIdHelperText}
/>
```

Here I have the state variable:

```js
const [selectedOrganization, setSelectedOrganization] = useState<
  OrganizationOut | undefined
>(undefined);
```

```js
export type OrganizationOut = {
  name?: string;
  barionId?: string;
```

And it keeps retain the empty string, does not matter what I write there, it is always empty.

When before an atomic string was displayed, it worked, but now as it is wrapped in an object, does not. Do you know why?

---

1 got this error, when using ANSWER 1

```js
./pages/[lang]/onboarding2.tsx:645:51
Type error: Argument of type '(preState: OrganizationOut | undefined) => { szamlazzhuSzamlaAgentKulcsTemp: string; name?: string | undefined; barionId?: string | undefined; barionIdTemp?: string | undefined; ... 18 more ...; urlPrefix?: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<OrganizationOut | undefined>'.
  Type '(preState: OrganizationOut | undefined) => { szamlazzhuSzamlaAgentKulcsTemp: string; name?: string | undefined; barionId?: string | undefined; barionIdTemp?: string | undefined; ... 18 more ...; urlPrefix?: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to type '(prevState: OrganizationOut | undefined) => OrganizationOut | undefined'.
    Call signature return types '{ szamlazzhuSzamlaAgentKulcsTemp: string; name?: string | undefined; barionId?: string | undefined; barionIdTemp?: string | undefined; szamlazzhuSzamlaAgentKulcs?: string | undefined; ... 17 more ...; urlPrefix?: string | undefined; }' and 'OrganizationOut | undefined' are incompatible.
      The types of 'events' are incompatible between these types.
        Type '{ [eventId: string]: EventOut; } | undefined' is not assignable to type '{ [eventId: string]: EventOut; }'.
          Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{ [eventId: string]: EventOut; }'.

  643 |                           selectedOrganization.szamlazzhuSzamlaAgentKulcsTemp =
  644 |                             event.target.value;
> 645 |                           setSelectedOrganization((preState) => ({
      |                                                   ^
  646 |                             ...preState,
  647 |                             szamlazzhuSzamlaAgentKulcsTemp: event.target.value!,
  648 |                           }));
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you setState object wrong way.

```
setSelectedOrganization(preState => ({ ...preState, barionId: event.target.value }));
```

You can read detail from [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> state is a reference to the component state at the time the change is
> being applied. It should not be directly mutated. Instead, changes
> should be represented by building a new object based on the input from
> state and props.

Comment: Thanks, works, would you explain why, what is the difference?

Comment: I added the doc

Comment: thanks, would you help a bit more? Do you know why I got the error message attached to question, when I run `yarn build`?

Answer (score 1):

**Never** modify the actual state. The state should be used as a read-only value that represents the state's value maintained by React. However, any changes on it do not modify the actual state. That's what `setState` is for.

Second of all, React uses a `===` comparison to check if the state has been changed. When you pass an array or an object to the `setState` function, it compares by reference, not by value. That means that you have to create a new object or array, and not use the same one:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({});

state.a = 5; // Mistake: never modify the actual state!
setState(state); // Mistake: setState will not update because reference is the same
```

Instead, you need to create a new object (or array) out of the current state, modify it, and then finally use it for the `setState`:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({});

const newState = {...state}; // Create a shallow copy of the state
newState.a = 5; // Modify the copy, and not the real state
setState(newState); // Set the state to the copy, that has a different reference
```